# Explanation of integer and register constant character in function

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
char firstmatch(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *temp;
    temp = s1;
    do {
        if (strchr(s2, *temp) != 0)
            return temp;
        temp++;
    } while (*temp != 0);
    return 0;
}

char *strchr(register const char *s, int c) {
    do {
        if (*s == c) {
            return (char*)s;
        }
    } while (*s++);
    return (0);
}
```

I am new to programming and I have been given this code which finds the first character in a string `s1` that is also in string `s2`. The task is to understand the C code and convert into Assembly code. As of right now my focus is just to understand what the C code is doing and I am currently having difficulty with pointers. I can sort through the code on the `firstmatch()` function and make my way down but I am kind of confused with the `char * strchr()` function. I am unable to understand whats the point of `int c` in regards to a constant character pointer? I'd appreciate if somebody could help explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `strchr()` in your code sample is an incomplete implementation of the Standard C library function that locates the first occurrence of a character in a C string, if any.

The argument has type `int` for historical reasons: in early versions of the language functions arguments would be typed only if the implicit type `int` did not suffice. character arguments were passed as `int` values, so typing the argument differently was unnecessary.

The `register` keyword is obsolete: early C compilers were not as advanced as current ones and the programmer could help code generators determine which variables to store in CPU registers by adorning their definitions with the `register` keyword. Modern compilers are more efficient and usually beat programmers at this game, hence this keyword is mostly ignored nowadays.

Note however that this implementation behaves differently from the Standard function: the value of `c` must be converted to `char` before the comparison. As noted by chux, all functions in `<string.h>` treat bytes in C strings and memory blocks as unsigned chars for comparison purposes.

Here is a more readable version with the correct behavior:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strchr(const char *str, int c) {
    const unsigned char *s = (const unsigned char *)str;
    do {
        if (*s == (unsigned char)c) {
            return (char *)s;
        }
    } while (*s++ != '\0');
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: UV for a good implementation. Pedantic detail: (Only needed for high portability). `*s == (char)c` is potentially not the right sign type for the compare per "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)."  §7.23.1 3. Consider `const unsigned char *us = s; ... if (*us == (unsigned char) c) { ... *us++ != '\0'`. With common 2's complement, not needed though, only an issue for very rare others as signed compare does not distinguish -0, +0.

Comment: @chux: you are correct, but this is really extreme and most probably irrelevant for all real systems: I am willing to bet that a system with sign/magnitude or one's complement representations for integers, especially `char`, must have `unsigned char` by default to be conformant.

Comment: We certainly agree to the extremer rarity of this concern.

Answer (score 0):

The `int c` argument might as well be `char c`. The type of `*temp` is `char`.

The strchr function takes a pointer into a nul terminated string and a char and either returns the pointer to the next occurrence of the char or null if it reached the nul at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`strchr()` receives a pointer to (think, memory address of) the first (or the only) character in a sequence.
The function extracts a character from memory using that pointer `s` and sees if its value matches the value of `c`. If there's a match, it returns the pointer.
If there's no match, it advances the pointer to the next character in the sequence (that is, increments the memory address by 1) and repeats.
If there's no match and the value of the character from memory is 0, `NULL` is returned.

The pointer being to a `const char` implies that memory isn't going to be written to, but may be read from. Indeed, the function never tries to write using the pointer.

So, you read chars from memory and compare them to an int. In most expressions `chars` implicitly convert to `signed int` (if such a conversion is generally possible without loss of any value of type `char`) or `unsigned int` (otherwise). See [integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) on this. If after this both sides of the `==` operator are signed ints, everything is trivial, just compare those. If one is `unsigned int` (the promoted `*s` character) while the other one is `signed int` (`c`), the signed one is converted to unsigned (see the same linked article for the logic/rules), after which both sides of `==` have the same type (`unsigned int`) and are comparable (this is one of the key ideas of C, most binary operators convert their inputs to a common type and produce the result of that common type).

Simply put, in C you can compare different arithmetic types and the compiler will insert necessary (per the language rules) conversions. That said, not all conversions preserve value (e.g. a conversion from `signed int` to `unsigned int` doesn't preserve negative values, however they are converted in a well-defined manner) and that may be surprising (e.g. `-1 > 1u` evaluates to 1, which seems absurd to anyone knowing a bit of math), especially to the ones new to the language.

The real question here seems "Why isn't `c` defined as `char`?".
If one inspects the standard C library functions, they'll find that values of type `char` are (almost?) never passed or returned, although passing or returning pointers to `char` is quite common. Individual characters are typically passed by means of the `int` type. The reason for this is probably that, like mentioned above, `char` would convert to `int` or `unsigned int` in an expression anyway, so some additional conversions (back to `char` and then again to `int`) may be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

The char *s1 represents a string in C.
The 0 represents the Acsii equivalent of '\0' which is the termination of a string in C. Chars and integers are interchangeable, but you need to know the Ascii value of each char. The letter 'A' is equivalent to integer 65 by Ascii value. This should answer your question about int c. It doesn't make any behavioral difference for the code.

Now suppose you had the string hello and meh, you would have:

```
    char * s1 = ['h', 'e','l','l','o','\0'] 
    char * s2 = ['m', 'e', 'h','\0']
```

So you call:

```
firstmatch('hello', 'meh')
```

temp is assigned the value of 'hello'.

Now you call

```
strchr('meh', 'h')
```

*temp in this case scenario is equivalent to temp[0], which is 'h'.

In the strchr, it loops through each letter of 'meh', starting from 'm'.

```
First iteration: 
'm' == 'h' -> false therefore proceed to next letter (*s++)
Second iteration: 
'e' == 'h' -> false therefore proceed to next letter (*s++)
Third iteration: 
'h' == 'h' -> true therefore return a char value that is not 0.
```

This returns us to the firstmatch function inside the if condition.
Since the if condition passes on the third iteration, it returns us 'h'.

Suppose the third iteration failed, it would increment onto the next letter in s1, which would be 'e', and follow the same procedure described above.

Finally, the (*temp != 0) means that if we encounter the '\0' in the s1 for 'hello' we defined above, then it stops the entire loop and returns 0. Indicating there is no same letter.

Read about pointer arithmetic in C/C++ if you don't understand why *temp == temp[0]. Likewise *temp++ == temp[n+1] (n representing the current character).

Comment: I am still confused. Assuming, the 2 strings are, str1 ="hello" stored at address 100 and str2 = "meh" stored at 104.Starting with function firstmatch: 
 s1 should be 100 and s2,104.
*s1 = "hello" pointing towards the first character 'h' and *s2 = "meh" pointing at 'm'.
temp is same as s1.
Now the strchr function is called with arguments s2 and *temp. At the strchr function:
register const *s = "m" but shouldn't the second argument be a character argument containing 'h' from string 1. Why am i comparing to int c? Or is it smart enough to change the value of 'h' to the ascii value?

Comment: Yes, C is smart enough to change it automatically. Int and char values are interchangeable. 'A' == 65 is equivalent to 65 == 65. 
It would probably be better for them to compare char to char for clarity, but char to int still works just as well.